# Dropdown onclick, close on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

Previously I got a header with a dropdown that was displayed on hover.
I wanted to change this to onclick.

The dropdown currently displays onclick, but when clicking again the dropdown does not close. It only close when the mouse navigate off the div.

How can I change this, so that the dropdown will always be open, and only can be closed by clicking somewhere on the website or on the event?

Code:

```
<a href="#header-cart" class="skip-link skip-cart <?php if($_cartQty <= 0): ?> no-count<?php endif; ?>">
    <span class="icon"></span>
    <span class="label"><?php echo $this->__('Cart'); ?></span>
    <span class="count"><?php echo $_cartQty; ?></span>
</a>

<div id="header-cart" class="block block-cart skip-content">
    <div class="block block-progress opc-block-progress minicart-wrapper">
      <div class="block-title-cartsidebar">SHOPPINGCART</div>
        <p class="empty"><?php echo $this->__('You have no items in your shopping cart.') ?></p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I use this code for the dropdown on the website:

```
    <?php //Drop-down ?>
    var ddOpenTimeout;
    var dMenuPosTimeout;
    var DD_DELAY_IN = 200;
    var DD_DELAY_OUT = 0;
    var DD_ANIMATION_IN = 0;
    var DD_ANIMATION_OUT = 0;

    $('.clickable-dropdown > .dropdown-heading').click(function() {
        $(this).parent().addClass('open');
        $(this).parent().trigger('mouseenter');
    });

    //$('.dropdown-heading').on('click', function(e) {
    $(document).on('click', '.dropdown-heading', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.dropdown', function() {

        var ddToggle = $(this).children('.dropdown-heading');
        var ddMenu = $(this).children('.dropdown-content');
        var ddWrapper = ddMenu.parent(); <?php //$(this); ?>

        <?php //Clear old position of dd menu ?>
        ddMenu.css("left", "");
        ddMenu.css("right", "");

        <?php //Show dd menu ?>
        if ($(this).hasClass('clickable-dropdown'))
        {
            <?php //If dropdown is opened (parent already has class 'open') ?>
            if ($(this).hasClass('open'))
            {
                $(this).children('.dropdown-content').stop(true, true).delay(DD_DELAY_IN).fadeIn(DD_ANIMATION_IN, "easeOutCubic");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            <?php //Add class 'open' to dd ?>
            clearTimeout(ddOpenTimeout);
            ddOpenTimeout = setTimeout(function() {

                ddWrapper.addClass('open');

            }, DD_DELAY_IN);

            //$(this).addClass('open');
            $(this).children('.dropdown-content').stop(true, true).delay(DD_DELAY_IN).fadeIn(DD_ANIMATION_IN, "easeOutCubic");
        }

        <?php //Set new position of dd menu.
              //This code is delayed the same amount of time as drop-down animation. ?>
        clearTimeout(dMenuPosTimeout);
        dMenuPosTimeout = setTimeout(function() {

            if (ddMenu.offset().left < 0)
            {
                var space = ddWrapper.offset().left; <?php //Space available on the left of dd ?>
                ddMenu.css("left", (-1)*space);
                ddMenu.css("right", "auto");
            }

        }, DD_DELAY_IN);

    }).on('mouseleave', '.dropdown', function() {

        var ddMenu = $(this).children('.dropdown-content');
        clearTimeout(ddOpenTimeout); <?php //Clear, to close dd on mouseleave ?>
        ddMenu.stop(true, true).delay(DD_DELAY_OUT).fadeOut(DD_ANIMATION_OUT, "easeInCubic");
        if (ddMenu.is(":hidden"))
        {
            ddMenu.hide();
        }
        $(this).removeClass('open');
    });
```

Comment: would you privide the generated html of your php code. i cannot see any HTML of DropDown-Menu  in your Code!

Comment: Demo in jsfiddle will be welcomed! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

still i cannot see any HTML of DropDown-Menu.
you use `$('.clickable-dropdown .....` where is this Element and its Sub-Elements?

> How can I change this, so that the dropdown will always be open, and
>   only can be closed by clicking somewhere on the website or on the
>   event?

here is a very simple Example of how a DropDown-Menu could be implemented!
its just a DEMO:

http://jsfiddle.net/f43yh0jk/4/

**HTML**:

```
<div class="TREE">
    <div class="NODE">
        <a class="NODE-LINK" href="/test">ABOUT</a>
        <div class="NODES">
            <div class="NODE">
                <a class="NODE-LINK">MY STORY</a>
            </div>
            <div class="NODE">
                <a class="NODE-LINK">MY STYLE</a>
            </div>
            <div class="NODE">
                <a class="NODE-LINK">MY STYLE X</a>
            </div>
            <div class="NODE">
                <a class="NODE-LINK">MY STYLE Y</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><div class="NODE">
        <a class="NODE-LINK">SERVICE</a>
        <div class="NODES">
            <div class="NODE">
                <a class="NODE-LINK">MY PRICING</a>
            </div>
            <div class="NODE">
                <a class="NODE-LINK">SERVICES</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.TREE{
    background: #3f4c6b;
}

.TREE > .NODE{
    background: #313654;
    display: inline-block;
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
    border-right: 1px solid #3f4c6b;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.TREE > .NODE:FIRST-CHILD{
    border-left: 0px solid #000;
}
.TREE > .NODE:LAST-CHILD{
    border-right: 0px solid #000;
}

.TREE > .NODE:HOVER{
    background: #3f4c6b;
}

.TREE > .NODE a.NODE-LINK{
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFF;
}

.TREE > .NODE .NODES{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 100%;
    background: #3f4c6b;
    padding: 5px;
    display: none;
}

.TREE > .NODE .NODES .NODE a.NODE-LINK{
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.TREE > .NODE .NODES .NODE:HOVER{
    background: #313654;
}
```

**JS/JQuery:**

```
    $(".TREE > .NODE > a").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
});
$(".TREE > .NODE").click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).parent().find(".NODE").not(this).find(".NODES").slideUp();
    $(this).find(".NODES").slideToggle();
});

$(document).click(function(event ) {    
    $(".TREE .NODES").slideUp();
});
```